# Is it possible to query Process Builders via the API?

Tags: apex

Is it possible to query Process Builders or Flows via the API (workbench, for example)? I cannot see these as any sObject options when trying to query for them.

It would be helpful to query them for the their names and respective Ids.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find both flows and processes using Workbench:

> Info => Metadata Types & Components => Flow for Flows
>
> Info => Metadata Types & Components => FlowDefinition for Processes