# Can we query all processbuilder exist in system for an object. I am creating a document for a team

Tags: query, process-builder, metadata-api

Is there any way I can export or query any process builder exist for particular objects from Org. I am creating a documentation for a quite complex org where there are many process builder each object.

Thanks

Comment: You could start here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120337/is-it-possible-to-query-process-builders-via-the-api

Comment: Thanks Arnold. Can you please check if I am correct. FLow Means WorkFlows on Workbench and FlowDefination means Process Builder